# Cookies disappear from a PWA each time a user restarts their phone

Tags: javascript, android, google-chrome, cookies, progressive-web-apps

I have a web app that uses a cookie as an access token (to let users stay logged in after refreshing/closing the site/app). It works perfectly on desktop but when I try to use it on my Android phone (installing it via Chrome), for some reason it says that I'm not logged in which means it wasn't able to load the access token.

Why is this happening? Is there a difference between how cookies are handled in the browser and when starting a PWA as a standalone?

Also two little side questions, 1, is there a way to debug a PWA that's added to the homescreen (using some sort of remote debugger) and 2, would it be a security risk to use localStorage for storing the access token instead of a cookie? I realize neither is particularly safe but I read that cookies are slightly better for this sort of thing. localStorage works just fine when starting as a standalone